# React Native Linking url event never fires

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

When opening my app in simulator via a deeplink, [url event](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#addeventlistener) never fires.

Note that `getInitialurl` works if app was closed.
But if app is already open and I run `npx uri-scheme open "mychat://bar" --ios`, app focuses but no url event fires...

Anyone had this problem ?

I'm running XCode 13.4.1
MacOS 12.5.1
React Native 0.70

[repo to reproduce bug](https://github.com/leoparis89/deeplink)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was adding the required code block of AppDelegate below @interface AppDelegate, but have to add inside @implementation AppDelegate which below interface.

Comment: @Lev you could have at least marked this one as the accepted answer to give him the credits? This literally suggested the right solution for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The event needs some additional configuration within your AppDelegate.m file in order to emit the events as mentioned in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/#setup-on-ios). Either open your Project from XCode and edit AppDelegate.m or open ./ios/{YOUR_PROJECT_NAME}/AppDelegate.m (or AppDelegate.mm) file and add the following lines at the end of the file before the @end tag comes:

```
// Add this inside `@implementation AppDelegate` above `@end`:
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

// Add this inside `@implementation AppDelegate` above `@end`:
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

@end
```

**Important:** If you get this working, you have two ways of handling the deeplink event and you have to handle them seperately! I think the second one will help you to solve your problem.

*1 - The app is closed and will open by the deeplink:*

```
Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => { 
   if(url != null) {
       //DoSomethingWithUrl
   }
});
```

*2 - The app is already running and will be focused using deeplink:*

```
Linking.addEventListener('url',(url)=>{ 
   if(url != null) {
       //DoSomethingWithUrl
   }
});
```

Putting these lines within your apps view and assumed your app has some sort of state (e.g. using the useState hook or redux) it'll called on every state change that occurs, due to everything beside the state itself will be re-rendered on changing the state. Therefore I would suggest you to call these two methods only one time when app is starting and you can  accomplish that by doing so:

```
const [isInitialStart, setInitialStart] = useState(true);
if(isInitialStart){
    Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => { 
        if(url != null) {
            //DoSomethingWithUrl
        }
    });
    Linking.addEventListener('url',(url)=>{ 
        if(url != null) {
            //DoSomethingWithUrl
        }
    });
    setInitialStart(false); 
}
```

I hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: The additional config is obviously stated in the docs and I had already applied it.
Still url event never fires.
See this issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34701

Have you been able yourself to make example 2 work ? Just curious. Thanks

Comment: Yes I'm using deeplinking in several applications, in various scenarios (payment redirections, oauth...). It works fine so far. I've checked your AppDelegate.mm file in the repo. Could you just try to define the continueUserActivity as mentioned above in your AppDelegate. If that not works try to apply the changes suggested in the bug report on react-native (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35577). I found this bug while upgrading my project to a new react-native version.

Comment: Thanks for having looked in the repo.
Event after adding continueUserActivity in AppDelegate.m
url event doesn't fire for deepLinks or universalLinks. Only getInitialUrl works ! :(

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the bug with this repo ?
https://github.com/leoparis89/deeplink

Answer (score 0):

if you use `react native +0.71`

change `AppDelegate.m` to `AppDelegate.mm`

```
// Add the header at the top of the file:
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

// Add this inside `@implementation AppDelegate` above `@end`:
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

// Add this inside `@implementation AppDelegate` above `@end`:
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}
```